# include javascript files in wordpress theme using functions.php file

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i have theses javascript files ->

```
 bootstrap.min.js;
                            jquery-1.10.1.min.js
                            modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js

function wpt_register_js() {
 wp_register_script( 'jquery.bootstrap.min', 
get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js',
 'jquery' ); 
wp_enqueue_script('jquery.bootstrap.min');
 }
```

and now to add other scripts do i need make a new function for each of the scripts  or can i use the same function for all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrap file can go in the footer. Modernizr has to go in the header.

To include these JS file do the following:

```
function wpse_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js', array(), '2.6.2' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_scripts' );
```

You don't need to enqueue jQuery. By defining it as a dependency for the second script it will load automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_in_queue_and_register_custom_scripts' );

  function add_in_queue_and_register_custom_scripts(){
     wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js' );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js', array( 'jquery', 'my-script' ) );
  }
```